# Install Wildcard Certificate onto AWS EC2 Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I'm having trouble. I followed a guide that I found here

http://www.thenetworkadministrator.net/index.php/2011/12/iis-ssl-certificate-into-amazon-elastic-load-balancer/

And exported by cert and created all those files, but it doesn't tell you which file goes in which field. I tried what I think is all the combinations but it doesn't accept it

I Setup the balancer as follows

[image]

Then I try to setup the certificate

[image]

Then you can see it tells me it's invalid.

In case it helps I exported from IIS and followed the tutorial on the link provided and the certificate is a DigiCert Wildcard Certificate ie (*.domain.com)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please read the post: [AWS Load Balancer SSL limitations](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/2011/04/aws-load-balancer-ssl-limitations.html/). The following solution worked for me:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -text
```

Then copy and paste the produced output between (including):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

AWS Load Balancer had accepted this key successfully.

Comment: The link to the referred post is dead.

Comment: Thanks, both formats look almost the same, lost a couple hours around this one.

Comment: In my case the ELB wizard complained about in 'Invalid Public Key Certificate' when in fact my private key format was incorrect. Your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmh, everything looks correct at first sight, but let's double check on a few details.

> And exported by cert and created all those files, but it doesn't tell
>   you which file goes in which field.

I can't quite follow, insofar the linked guide clearly states where to put he files:

> **When prompted for the certificate keys do the following:**
>
> - Open the file server.key that was created from above with openssl and paste into the Private Key textbox
> - Open the file cert.pem that was created from above with openssl and copy the text from —-BEGIN till the end of the file and paste that
>     into Public Key Certificate textbox
>
> *Note: I did not put anything into the certificate chain*

The screenshot you provided indicates you have chosen the correct combination in fact, however ...

> I tried what I think is all the combinations but it doesn't accept it

... I assume you have deliberately shortened the textarea input widgets for *Private Key* and *Public Key Certificate* to decrease image size or hide the actual keys? Otherwise the text to be pasted has mostly gone lost somehow, insofar it should look something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICeDCCAeGgAwIBAgIGAOABb24uY29tMQwwCgb3DQEBBQUAMFMxCzAJBgNVBAYT
[...]
A WHOLE LOT MORE HEX DIGITS HERE!
[...]
q04lCMxITAfBgNVBAMTAAJW26+adw9C063H7I846ZbxHl6BkcTPsjL3b5JoZhyim
jbzH4dktTFNIkX4o
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In this regard another cause might be addressed by this answer to [Public key and private cert don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763240/45773):

> Looks like the issue was the way in which I was copying the contents
>   of the key and certs into the AWS Management console. I was using an
>   Ubuntu desktop running in Virtual Box [...] Once I opened the key and 
>   cert files on the same box as
>   the web browser (Windows in this case) the certs went through just
>   fine. I'm guessing some parts of the file aren't making it over
>   correctly when using the shared clip board between Virtual Box client
>   and host.

Given the high probability of special characters appearing in the hex dump, this is entirely possible for various similar copy&paste scenarios as well, e.g. between SSH terminals with erroneous character encoding settings etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest/most concise explanation that I have come across for creating a self-signed cert for AWS ELBs is...

```
openssl genrsa -out server_privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server_privatekey.pem -out server_certificate_csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server_certificate_csr.pem -signkey server_privatekey.pem -out server_certificate.pem
```

And then in AWS;

Certificate Name: mycert

Private key: [content of server_privatekey.pem]

Public key: [content of server_certificate.pem]

Certificate Chain: [content of server_certificate_csr.pem]

Credit: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=381093