# Make AWS load balancer support HTTPS without a domain

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have built an application which has no front-end at all. I need no user to access it. However I need to expose an endpoint to complete a Oauth 2 protocol. I'm exposing it using an AWS load balancer.

In order to make it work I need the load balancer to support HTTPS.
I understand I need add a HTTPS listener with port 443 to the load balancer and register a TLS/SSL certificate. However, when trying to request a certificate I am asked to provide a domain which I don't have as the load balancer dns e.g. `http://my-app-XXXXXX.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` is enough.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding one ground concept regarding why do I need the domain for requesting the certificate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add HTTPS Listener to Application Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683235/add-https-listener-to-application-load-balancer)