# APNS setup for the server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to setup our APNS server. I was looking at the instructions on this page:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

I'm understanding everything. Problem is that I have a website already SSL enables (SSL terminates at the load balancer) on AWS, following these instructions a while back:

["Public key certificate and private key doesn't match" when using Godaddy issued certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753619/how-do-i-setup-ssl-certs-on-amazon-aws-load-balancer-using-godaddy-certificates)

The website for APNS is telling me to get a CSR file, etc. But if I already have this SSL certification done, does it mean I have to start from scratch and re-key my key? :( I wasn't able to find information regarding this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APNS CSR has nothing to do with any certificates you already have.

You have to create certificates in the developer area of apples websites. You don't install those certificates to the web server... they are only used from the php script on your server to connect to the apple server as a client. Your script has to load them while they run.. but they are not installed in the web server or load balancer.