# Godaddy certificates with aws elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

I am having a lot of difficulty in adding my private key and certificate that I obtained from godaddy in aws elb. It always says "Key provided does not match with the provided certificate. My files are in following format.

Private key ---> .key

Two certs files provided by godaddy ---> .crt

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I use cat command on terminal to copy the contents and then paste it using chrome browser in ubuntu 16.04.
I read the following answers ([answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753619/public-key-certificate-and-private-key-doesnt-match-when-using-godaddy-issued.)) to convert .key and .csr to .pem but they still give the same error.

Any lead will be very helpful.

Even following command always give me error

aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name www.example.com-2013010-2014010 --certificate-body file://www.example.com.crt --private-key file://www.example.com.key --certificate-chain file://certchan.key

```
An error occurred (KeyPairMismatch) when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: The private key did not match the public key provided. Please verify the key material and try again.
```

Comment: If they gave you two certs, you may have confused one for the other?  Only one can be the server certificate. Just double check.

Comment: *"convert .key and .csr to .pem"* ...you should not be using your CSR file in this process.  Please clarify.